# printing order details and products short description

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a button that prints the order details. The names of the products and the short description (on the website all the accessories are shown as a table in the short description) The problem is when I try to add the short description of each product the order edit page crashes or the button opens the order url again This is the code that works great without the failed attempt of adding a short description.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxesws');
function add_meta_boxesws()
{
    add_meta_box('custom_order_meta_box', __('print order details'), 'custom_metabox_content', 'shop_order', 'normal', 'default');
}

function custom_metabox_content()
{
    $post_id = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : false;
    if (!$post_id) return; // Exit

    $value = "abc";
    ?>
    <p><a href="?post=<?php echo $post_id; ?>&action=edit&abc=<?php echo $value; ?>" class="button" id="print-order"><?php _e('print'); ?></a></p>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var printButton = document.getElementById('print-order');
            if (printButton) {
                printButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    printOrderDetails();
                });
            }

            function printOrderDetails() {
                var orderDetails = '<?php echo get_order_details($post_id); ?>';
                if (orderDetails) {
                    var printWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
                    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Order Details</title></head><body>');
                    printWindow.document.write('<h1>Order Details</h1>');
                    printWindow.document.write(orderDetails);
                    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    printWindow.document.close();
                    printWindow.print();
                } else {
                    alert('Error fetching order details.');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function get_order_details($order_id)
{
    // Check if WooCommerce is active
    if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
        // Get the order object
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        // Check if the order exists
        if ($order) {
            // Get the total cost of the order
            $total_cost = $order->get_total();

            // Get the list of products in the order
            $products = $order->get_items();

            // Prepare the order details string
            $order_details = "Order ID: " . $order_id . "<br>";
            $order_details .= "Total Cost: " . wc_price($total_cost) . "<br>";
            $order_details .= "Products:<br>";

            // Loop through each product and add its details to the string
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product_name = $product->get_name();
                $order_details .= "- " . $product_name . "<br>";
            }           
            $x = new WC_Order($order_id);

foreach ($x->get_items() as $item)
{
    $product_description = get_post($item['product_id'])->post_content;
}           
            return $order_details;
        }
    }

    // Return an empty string if WooCommerce is not active or the order is not found
    return '';
}
```

I need to find how to add a line to the function get_order_details that will also attach the short description without problems.